# Infinity error - Project Euler # 26 - Reciprocal Cycles

Tags: java

I'm receiving an error in Eclipse when attempting to solve Problem # 26 from Project Euler.

I DO NOT WANT THE SOLUTION! Please.

If you can give me a suggestion only as to why I receive "infinity" as an output please fill me in. I've tried Googling this but it's difficult not to accidentally see the solution and I'd rather do this with as little help as possible.

The infinity error is after p=309. This may not be an 'error' at all, perhaps it's simply truncating something. I have tried long and BigInteger, but it did not seem to help.

Here is the problem posed in PE # 26:

Here's my code:

```
public class Reciprocal_Cycles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double b = 10;
        double p;
        for (p = 1; p < 1000; p++) {
            if (p % b != 0)

            System.out.println(((Math.pow(b, p - 1) - 1)) / p + "       " + p);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> The infinity error is after `p=309`.

The largest number that a `double` can represent is about `1.8e+308`, and `Math.pow(10, 309)` is larger than this. When a floating-point computation overflows like this, you get `+inf`.

Also, I'd be careful when using `p % b != 0` with floating-point variables.